# WoMan italic `\,VARIABLE\/ representation

Tags: man

When I do `M-x woman => ln` , as you can see italic variables are represened as in between following pattern `\,`  - `\/`. How could I revmoe or fix it?

### [image]

Setup:

```
(setenv "MANWIDTH" "72")

(defadvice man (before my-woman-prompt activate)
      (interactive (progn
                     (require 'woman)
                     (list (woman-file-name nil)))))

(require 'woman)
(set-face-attribute 'woman-bold nil :inherit font-lock-type-face :bold t)
(set-face-attribute 'woman-italic :inherit font-lock-keyword-face :underline t)
```

Bug track link: https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=42219

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Congratulations, you've found a bug.  `\,` and `\/` are space-adjusting escape sequences for groff this package doesn't handle yet.  https://www.gnu.org/software/groff/manual/groff.html#Ligatures-and-Kerning explains how they work, but it's unclear what part of the package to adjust for that.

I suggest you to use `M-x report-emacs-bug` and edit the link to the bug report into this question for tracking.

Comment: Response on the bug track: `I think the right solution here is just make woman ignore these kerning operators, so I've done that in Emacs 28.`